# How to use actuator as sensor to play animation of my character?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a character that has a walk animation. I assigned a steering actuator to it specifically path following so that they will all meet in a specific place by themselves. I also have a shake animation for my building/plane. I've already set sensors and actuators to it too. If I run it and press enter, the building/plane starts to shake something like that in an earthquake. The thing I would like to do next is when I run it, my characters should only start to move towards their target if the plane starts to shake (that is if enter key is pressed). If no shaking, the characters should just walk in their place. They should only move if shaking occurs. I've been playing around with sensors and actuators but I can't seem to find a solution for this. What do you think could be the best approach for this problem?

Here's my blend file: [canteen ver 2.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwcsNFrXW6LrdU5HcnJCQ3NWTjg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is give each person a status property.

[image]

A sensor tests the status and while it is 0 have them play an idle action.

[image] [image]

A message sensor then receives an evacuate message and sets the status to 1.

[image] [image]

When the status is 1 play an evacuate action or use steering to seek the evacuation point.

[image] [image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your help! But in the message sensor and actuators though, I can't seem to make it work. I think giving them properties will work but I think my message sensor cannot detect any message.. Am I doing it right? When I press the enter key, my plane shakes and then sends message to my human. And my human should have message sensor to detect it right? It seems it cannot receive any message. What could be the problem? :(

Comment: Actually it would appear that the property test sensor fails to compare strings, Change them to use integer. You can have a look at a small test file [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27657)